# Keyboard Interruption Error - Using Control C while program is running to put in authentication code

Tags: python

I am getting a keyboard interruption error for trying to mount my drive cause I am pressing control c to put the authentication code in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to press `Ctrl-C` to put authentication code in?

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+C` will abort (Cancel) your running script in an interpreter. If you want to actually **paste** something, you should be using `Ctrl + V`